# Converting VARCHAR with divide operand to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a `VARCHAR` which will return the value something like this '40/4'.

Is there a way to convert this `VARCHAR` to an `INT`? I tried casting but it is not working.

Sample:

```
Declare @test varchar(6) = '40/4'

Select cast (@test as int) * 4
```

Expected: 40

Actual:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '40/4' to data type int

Note: The value `40/4` is something coming from a message saved in one of the systems and that cannot be changed.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Sounds dangerous. What if the parameter contained `1; DROP TABLE Transactions; --`

Answer (score 0):

`CAST`/`CONVERT` won't work because `'40/4'` is not a number, its a string that happens to represent a mathematical expression.

One way to solve this is by using dynamic SQL e.g.

```
declare @test varchar(6) = '40/4';

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + @test + ' * 4';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Returns: 40

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after the first valid integer value before the `/` (or just the first non-numeric character) you can try

```
Declare @test varchar(6) = '40/4'

Select Try_Convert(int,Left(@test,IsNull(NullIf(PatIndex('%[^0-9]%',@test),0),6)-1))
```